# strip only specific tags (like <p>), but keep other tags (like <br/>)

Tags: posts, html, wp-editor, html-editor

I know it's easy to disable Wordpress from adding both `p` and `br` tags with:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

but I want Wordpress to keep adding `<br>` where there is a line break.
 I only use text editor, visual editor is disabled.
 It was working fine until the recent update to Wordpress 4.7 - now it is adding some closing `p` tags, without opening them like `</p>` .

even tried [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-automatic-p-tags/) plugin but it disables br tags as well.

Any way of just disabling `p` tags not `br` tags in post content? I can't find anything on the internet that says something about a solution.

Comment: This might be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248628/disable-wordpress-from-adding-p-tags

Comment: that is only saying about 'wpautop', which is the problem I specified here

Comment: You appear to have 2 distinct problems here, 1: how do I stop WP creating paragraph tags? 2: How do I add `br` tags to the whitelist? It looks like you've already solved problem 1, and need help solving problem 2. Is this correct?

Comment: @whiteord - Is that happening only while added the content or only by adding shortcode? I too experienced it but only when I used shortcodes.

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, I guess so.

Comment: @Maqk it is adding </p> with the wordress' audio player

Comment: @whitelord - Which theme are you using? Maybe theme is using any filters for preprocessors for the shortcodes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd better never disable those actions (what you say). Instead, insert `add_filter('the_content', 'MyFilter', 88 );` and create such function:

```
function MyFilter($content){
    $tags = array( 'p', 'span');
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////// HERE INSERT ANY OF BELOW CODE  //////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    return $content;
}
```

## ======== METHOD 1 =========

```
$content= preg_replace( '#<(' . implode( '|', $tags) . ')(.*|)?>#si', '', $content);
$content= preg_replace( '#<\/(' . implode( '|', $tags) . ')>#si', '', $content);
```

## ======== METHOD 2 ======

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $content= preg_replace('#<\s*' . $tag . '[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*'. $tag . '>#msi', '', $content);
}
```

## ======== METHOD 3 =========

**DOM** object (preferred): https://stackoverflow.com/a/31380542/2377343

Comment: thanks, but when using your function not even audio player will show. it removes quite a lot. not sure how to add all the tags to the list. even my divs won't show

Comment: even after adding them, and `span` it won't work. all the content si broke, and no embed or div will show

Comment: I've updated answer, using another method. see that.

Comment: wonderful! method 2 seems to work properly. will do a little more testing and then choose your answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work for me. why, is it better than method 2?

Comment: yes, but just removing the empty p tags will do for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51840/discussion-between-t-todua-and-whitelord).

Answer (score 0):

The "the_content" filter is used to filter the content of the post where filter function in `your_prefix_ptagfix` forces to find the `<p>` tags before and after the shortcodes opening tags.

Add The following code to your functions file and let me know if that helps.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_prefix_theme_setup' );
function your_prefix_theme_setup(){
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'your_prefix_ptagfix' );

}

function your_prefix_ptagfix($content){   
    $array = array (
        '<p>[' => '[', 
        ']</p>' => ']',
    );

    $content = strtr($content, $array);
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in an [edit] to your answer **why** your answer should solve the OPs problem?

Comment: added your code but the p tags are still added